# Is denying login after incorrect attempts ineffective?

Tags: authentication, passwords

Generally denying login attempts after X amounts of incorrect attempts for Y amount of tries is a very basic way to prevent bruteforce attempts or malicious login attempts.

Yet, surely doing this is meaningless if you allow successful login with the correct password? In which case getting an error or a warning message about a timeout period when trying an incorrect message is meaningless if the correct password will work regardless.

On Hotmail for example when I attempt to login with the wrong password *I eventually get a message saying further login attempts are restricted*. **Trying with the correct password lets me in straight away.** So I wonder if there is any point to having such a warning in the first place? Is it effective in the actual password grants access?

Comment: What do you mean it's all meaningless with the correct password? Do you mean if their account is locked out, and they log in with the correct password while its locked out?

Comment: @Sonny I think you are entirely missing the point. When it locks the user out for a period of time, it will not accept **any** password during that time, including a correct password.

Comment: @AttackingHobo, I understand that this is the idea, but in practice this is not what is happening, and a correct password will log in. I assume Hotmail and Gmail have done this to prevent simply DoS attacks, but it would seem to defeat the purpose.

Comment: I don't know what to say, and I don't really want to get my account locked right now, but before after I had changed my password to a new one, I forgot what it was for a bit, and got locked out. When I remembered it, it would not accept it yet.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence for your assertion that this is how gmail and hotmail work?  All the other reports are that you're wrong, and it would indeed be a huge error to implement it that way

Comment: @nealmcb, at least for me I have deliberately tried 10 incorrect passwords on my account, and get the warning, and then can log in immediately with my correct password.

Comment: @sonny on which email service (or services)?  What was the timing of the warning and of the subsequent success?  Perhaps it was just a short timeout (which is very effective against a major brute-force attempt).

Comment: @nealcmb, this is on hotmail and gmail, as tested. I logged in as soon as I saw the warning, as fast as any other logons....at a very maximum it took 5 seconds.

Comment: Gmail doesn't work like this. You have to enter a captcha to try additional passwords.  A correct password alone is not enough. This prevents online password guessing attacks.

Comment: @Jeff-InventorChromeOS the capctha is the difference I think. Care to expand that into an answer?

Answer (score 25):

Preventing login without the right password is the core functionality of the login process. Just keeping on doing that is by no means an "additional" security feature.

Denying login attempts after X incorrect attempts means rejecting *all* attempts in that situation, regardless of the value of the password which is then presented. If you still accept the right password, then you are not denying anything, you are just managing a login process.

With online systems, disabling the account is a bit rash; it means that anybody can effectively block your account by entering junk passwords. A smoother procedure is to add *delays*: after X incorrect passwords, have the server block the account for, say, one minute, and reblock it for one minute after every attempt until the right password is entered. The initial X attempts should be enough to cope with users with shaky fingers, and the one-per-minute rate severely impedes a bruteforcing attacker (coupled with some safety measures such as banning IPs from which too many login request come in too little time).

Comment: Plus, the actual account owner sees that someone was trying passwords on his account. If they'd just add a "list of last 1000 dates and IP-addresses that accessed your account", it would prevent a lot of "lurkers"...

Comment: Hi Thomas, great answer. I just noticed with Hotmail for example if you put in X amount of wrong passwords you get a message saying login attempts are disabled, but you can login immediately with the correct password. That seemed to be ineffective to me.

Comment: @Sonny, ineffective, yes, but also completely incorrect.

Comment: @AviD how is that completely incorrect? I try several incorrect passwords and get a message saying login attempts are restricted and can then logon with my correct password.

Comment: @Thomas Unforunately you risk denial of service attacks by locking the account unless it is session specific or some other means of only locking an account to a specific requester. There were a number of apps floating around back in the day that allowed attackers to send bogus login attempts to keep accounts locked permanently while they were running. However if you make it session specific then this too can be easily defeated by running the POST requests through a list of proxy servers.

Comment: this is a bad old answer

Comment: delays alone do not fix the problem they merely string out the time until the hack is finished.

Comment: really the password is prolly already part of one of the databases which contain heart bleed data so even a delay will not stop identify or stop them

Comment: @caseyr547, if they have the correct password from an earlier breach (and the user has the same password and hasn't changed it), then there is absolutely nothing we can do to prevent a hijack of that account.  This technique of delaying the login is only meant to prevent brute force attacks against an online system.  And yes, they don't "fix" the problem, they only string it out until it's impossible for the hacker to possibly try every password before the end of the solar system.

Answer (score 11):

The idea is to not even accept the correct password during lock down.

But before implementing a lock down system, it makes sense to look at the attack cases:

### a specific user is targeted

If the attacker is targeting a specific user, denying or delaying logins after a couple of wrong tries is helpful. A common mistake with the delaying approach is not to prevent parallel logins attempts.

Another common approach is to use CAPTCHAs to slow down the attacker. One needs to keep in mind that many standard CAPTCHAs are already broken. When the NY-Times voting was manipulated, the attackers crafted a special interface which display many CAPTCHAs on one page.

The attacker may try only two login attempts every day over a long period of time (we actually see this in Stendhal from time to time). Displaying the number of failed login attempts after a successful login may help here. It's important to not say "0 failed login attempts" every time because this will just teach the people to ignore that message. Only show the warning if there was at least one failed login attempt.

A list of ip-addresses and timestamps of the last login attempts (successful or not) may help, at least for users who care about security and have a certain level of knowledge.

### any user is target

In cases in which a really large number of logins are attempted, the attackers often pick a fixed password and brute force the account names. This means that a threshold of three login attempts per account will not be triggered.

So failed login attempts need to be tracked on a cross account basis, for example based on the ip-addresses.

### locking out a large number of users

Implementing the counter measurements mentioned above creates a new vulnerability: An attacker can lockout a large number of accounts. In some cases this may cause far greater damage to a site than a small number of hacked accounts.

IP-based counting can help to mitigate this attack vector. Or it can give a lever to it in situations in which lots of people are behind the same proxy server (at an university, or public wlan, etc.)

### locking out a specific account

In addition to the last section, an attacker may try to lockout a specific account. For example someone who is bidding against them on an auction.

It may be possible to use a second channel to allow the account owner to re-enable his account. For example by sending a mobile text message or email with a code.

Answer (score 8):

I like Thomas Pornin's answer.  My only addition would be - when you design a password lockout feature, you need to figure out how to support your user base and balance that with the risk of breakins.

In a high security system with a limited number of security-savvy users, dedicated admins and a big budget for user support, enabling a locked out password may be manual and may require a re-authentication through a secondary channel that is expensive and time consuming.

In a low-security system with a huge (and maybe even computer illiterate) user base - like Google or Hotmail - the risk of a break in is likely to be overruled by the expense of supporting account unlock through anything except a highly automated, very simple, process.

I've seen systems that were so simple, that all they did was force-close the browser when 3 bad passwords were reached.  Slightly better is the system Thomas proposed with a timeout on disabled accounts.  In my experience, systems do this to provide a moderate barrier to bruteforce attacks while balancing the needs of tons of users who are trying to access their accounts.

It's true that it's not the greatest approach - but systems need to find some way to slow down attacks while not dealing with users face to face, since every support call costs the provider money - so with free services like Gmail, you get what you pay for.

Comment: Right on! In my mind security is part of a delicate balancing act between usability, cost, and security. Make the system too expensive and no one will buy it (or you won't be able to cover your costs). Make the system too hard to use, and less people will want to use your system. Make it too insecure and you will lose the value you were trying to protect.

Comment: You must also take in account the ability for an attacker to lock out legitimate users. Too often I see systems like that acting as enabler to cheap denial of service.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you not only lock out a user profile that gets too many bad passwords ... but also block the IP of a machine that gets too many bad passwords (possibly with multiple accounts).

I use DenyHosts on my linux machines to block IP's that get try to guess passwords.

Answer (score 1):

I think **you should let the user determine how "random" his password is.**

For some "passwords", it just doesn't make sense to put a limit: some users generate their "passwords" automatically (making them impossible to remember) and keep these in a file, so these passwords are more like crypto keys than normal passwords.

I believe that **letting the user choose how many tries before the account gets a 10 s, 30 s, 1 mn login time penalty, and how many before the account is locked for 1 h, 12 h, 1 d, with or w/o CAPTCHA recourse** would force user to think more about the strength of their password.

Then you are not just giving some freedom to people, *you are forcing this freedom on users*: every user would have to choose a locking-out policy.

Also a user should be allowed to a link his account to some RBL to prevent login from open SOCKS relays or from Tor exits (defaulting to no RBL subscribed).

For Web applications, a user should have the right to choose between pure HTTP-based auth (HTTP-auth, cookies,...) or HTTP-based + IP addr-based auth (binding a logged-in user to one IP) (defaulting to just HTTP-based auth, no IP addr binding).

I think you should aggressively give freedom and responsibility to users. This way they cannot cry in forums when they have been hacked, saying that the password **system setup** was weak, insecure, non professional...

Comment: Any justification for the down vote?

Comment: Pretty much the same as the others I've addressed.  **Please join us in chat (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) or post in meta (http://meta.security.stackexchange.com) if you'd like to discuss this further.**

Comment: +1 because neither the downvote itself nor the link in answer make obvious sense

Comment: no this is bad users are not sec experts

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what type of account the user is attempting to access. Web based email accounts are the usual example where the email is the username, however in other cases it is better to not use the email as the username therefore the attacker would not have the user credentials in the first place in order to dictionary crack the password.

Any form of account locking without captchas or some other form of mass POST prevention can lead to denial of service where an attack tool is used to send multiple requests for the expressed purposes of causing account locks.

Using non-email or names is the standard with website account logins such as Godaddy and others, and also bank account logins for example, although these tend to be number strings which opens them up to user specific denial of service attacks via mass brute force attacks on number string blocks.

ex:
user: 1000000++
pass: a-zA-Z0-9

An attack sending 4 attempts on a sequential username where the bank has set the user to be a range of numbers like 48829387 could easily allow an attacker to deny logins to a large range of bank users by going over the limit of allowed incorrect password requests to random numbers between the ranges of say 4000000 and 4999999.

In most web login situations though, having users choose a username separate to their name or email address is asking a bit much, and is probably why banks often use number strings as usernames.

So if difficult usernames are not available as an option, then preventing dictionary hammering is the next port of call by either the use of captchas or even demanding javascript before establishing sessions as often these dictionary type attack tools lack the ability to deal with returning cookies let alone sessons established after javascript is detected.